# Add to home screen in React progressive web app

Tags: reactjs, redux, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to [apply this pattern for adding "add to home screen" functionality to a progressive web app](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) I'm building mainly for desktop use and I was wondering how this might be achieved using React.

I read this criteria for using add to home screen:

```
Meets a user engagement heuristic (currently, the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds)
```

But a console.log I dropped into the event handler for the `beforeinstallprompt` event is fired probably at most 5 seconds into loading the app, so I'm wondering how to apply this heuristic and control it since the advice only has me save an event for later use.  In the event that such a thing doesn't exist and I *must* manually save and use the event the way the site advises me to do, I was wondering if I already am using Redux, if that would be the best place to store this deferredPrompt event.  Thanks!

Comment: have you found a solution for this?